# Powershell - is it possible to level up a directory using a variable?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make this as easy as possible for end users, without their interaction. So I would like to use the

```
$PSScriptROOT
```

Then level up so lets say the script is stored in c:\temp\scripts\run I want to be able to get to C:\Temp\Scripts using the $PSScriptRoot and potentially adding

```
cd ..
```

I know I can't add this to a variable so is there away that I can get Powershell to recognise it as a command?

Comment: When you know you want to access `C:\Temp\Scripts` why don't you simply do a `Set-Location C:\Temp\Scripts`?

Comment: Are  you looking for `Set-Location $PSScriptRoot/..` or `$ScriptParent = Convert-Path $PSScriptRoot/..`? If not, please clarify what you're looking for, by directly updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

This was answer I was looking for,

```
$dir = (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot)
```

thanks for the help @-olaf & @-mklement0